# Как получить приватное поле SocketState из BluetoothSocket?

Tags: android

Как мне получить из BluetoothSocket значение SocketState?

Есть класс:

```
   public final class BluetoothSocket implements Closeable {
    //....
       private enum SocketState {
        INIT,
        CONNECTED,
        LISTENING,
        CLOSED,
    }

    /** prevents all native calls after destroyNative() */
    private volatile SocketState mSocketState;
    }
```

Возможно ли достать mSocketState ?
Стандартно он приватный и нету методом для его получения..

Comment: А что за `SocketState`? Не вижу такого в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте метод `getRemoteDevice().getBondState()` у [BluetoothSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html).

Comment: Нет, не то.. getRemoteDevice().getBondState() у меня всегда равен 10, а SocketState или Connected или CLOSE